# SQL insert query for avoiding duplicate row inserts

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the following SQL insert statement to insert values into a table `MY_DATA`, but here I want to add a check if the row already exists, based on data in column `CREATED_AT`.

```
INSERT INTO MY_DATA (SITE_ID, USER_NAME, USER_NO, CREATED_AT) 
VALUES (:siteId, :userName, :userNo, :createdAt)
```

Here if I try to insert the row with same value present in `CREATED_AT` column in the table it should not get inserted.

Using Oracle SQL developer for Database.

Please help I am new here.

Comment: I think you can create a unique index on that column.

Comment: Hi can you please explain it. Imagine index creation done in table for the column CREATED_AT. How that is going to help and what needs to change in query after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO MY_DATA dst
USING DUAL
ON (dst.created_at = :created_at)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT (SITE_ID, USER_NAME, USER_NO, CREATED_AT)
 VALUES (:siteId, :userName, :userNo, :createdAt);
```

You can create an index to prevent multiple insertions with the same `CREATED_AT` value:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_data__created_at__u ON my_data (created_at);
```

If you have that, then you can use your query in a PL/SQL statement and catch the exception (and then ignore it, report it or do whatever is required with it):

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MY_DATA (SITE_ID, USER_NAME, USER_NO, CREATED_AT) 
  VALUES (:siteId, :userName, :userNo, :createdAt);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    -- Handle the exception
    NULL;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you I am used merge statement and it's worked. However if I need to add a same condition for other column in future how to include here.

Comment: @VinodSP Just add it to the `ON` clause `ON (dst.created_at = :created_at AND dst.user_no = :userNo)` or for the index `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_data__created_at__u ON my_data (user_no, created_at);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to create a UNIQUE INDEX on your table on CREATE_AT column -

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_unq_created_at
ON MY_DATA (created_at);
```

After that you don't need to do anything in your query. This index will take care that no duplicate values are being inserted into created_at column in your table.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs this will also works but in my case there are already duplicate records present in the column so can't create unique index, and also I don't have right to modify the data in table.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use merge, e.g.

```
merge into my_data a
  using (select :siteId    site_id, 
                :userName  user_name, 
                :userNo    user_no, 
                :createdAt created_at
         from dual
        ) b
on (a.created_at = b.created_At)
when not matched then 
  insert (site_id, user_name, user_no, created_at)
  values (b.site_Id, b.user_Name, b.user_No, b.created_At);
```

Comment: Thank you it's worked. However if I need to add a same condition for other column in future how to include here.

Comment: Just add it to ON clause, e.g. (on (a.created_at = b.created_at and a.site_id = b.site_id and ...)